# Login form downloads log file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a Linux (Apache) server with Joomla at a host. Recently, all HTML forms started to download a page each time they were submitted. It would download e.g. index.php, but not with the same content. The content is about the same every time:

> Status: 303
>  Connection: close
>  Date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 15:58:49
>   GMT
>  Location: http://example.com/administrator/index.php
>   Server: Apache/2.2.22
>  Vary: Accept-Encoding
>  Content-Encoding:
>   gzip
>  Content-Length: 20
>  Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8
>  Client-Date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 15:58:51 GMT
>   Client-Peer: 194.63.000.000:80
>  Client-Response-Num: 1

After refreshing the page after the file was downloaded, I was actually logged in.

Comment: Check if PHP is installed?

Comment: @AmalMurali PHP is installed, ver. 5.5.17

Comment: You need to check if php is loaded on apache.  Look in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and search for php, and look in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ and see if there's anything php related

Comment: @JustinKiang I tried going to /etc, but I did not found a directory called httpd. Maybe that is because I'm on a shared server on a hosting.

Comment: @AppKongen: Try `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` instead.

Comment: @JustinKiang In /etc/apache2/ there is one folder, conf.d, and it contains a link to javascript-common.conf. Nothing else.

Comment: My bad, some distros has it in httpd.  Is there an /etc/apache2/apache2.conf?

Comment: No, /etc/ just contains conf.d

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an error with your Apache server and PHP. Have you tweaked any settings recently? Instead of the form executing the action you specify (the PHP login script for example) your web server is not actually serving the content so your browser is just downloading it.

Comment: The thing is: When I logged in to Joomla! administrator, it downloaded the file mentioned earlier. But, when I reloaded the page, I was logged in. I edited my original post.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!--?php
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", ""); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME",""); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");
?-->
```

See more at: http://www.discussdesk.com/download-login-form-in-PHP-and-mysql.htm#sthash.s8g1DDGC.dpuf

Comment: The error is not in the login script itself, but with all forms on the website. The administrator-login was just one example.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to this question. Additionally, we discourage answers from relying too much on external sites, since links break over time.